# Postgres split timestamp column to time column and date column

Tags: postgresql

Hi as the title says I have a column named healthtime in my table which is of type timestamp without timezone i.e.

```
Healthime
2012-02-02 08:15:00
```

I would like to split this into two new columns in the same table, one date column and one time column i.e.

```
Date        Time
2012-02-02  08:15:00
```

Please can someone advise me how to do this (preferably in a single query),

Thanks,
James

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because I am going to perform some data mining on the data and I want to be about to mine by specific dates without regard to the time...

Comment: You do know that you can do this "on the fly" using e.g.: `healthime::date` (you can also create an index on that, to speed up queries). You could create a view to make this easier in the front end.

Comment: I did think that but I am outputting to a text file and then feeding that as an input to the data mining so I just figured it would be easier to split the timestamp in the database for future functionality and queries... Also doing it this way means that an index is of no use.

Comment: Oh and also the reason for outputting the data required in a text file as opposed to performing it directly using database queries is so I can leave the mining running independent of the database.

Comment: Then a view sounds like a much better solution to me.

Comment: But a view will run the query every time it is referenced. Which will therefore mean that I will need the database server running and connected whenever I perform the mining.

Comment: I meant you can use the view to create the output file (or a simple select which cuts off the time part)

Comment: Ah thanks, I already have the code to output the file in the correct format for the mining i.e.: `Copy (select healthtime, status1, status2 from metastatus LIMIT 1000) To '/tmp/output1000.txt' WITH DELIMITER ' ';` This is less manual and more flexible I think?

Comment: Then simply replace `healthtime` with `healthtime::date`

Comment: I would still like to convert the healthtime to a separate date and time column within the database if possible? Just for flexibility... Plus I can then create an index as you said for other queries i.e. such as `select * from metastatus where date_column = "2013-04-04"`

Comment: Again, you can do that without changing the data. Just create a view and create an index on `healthtime::date`, it will be used when you run `select * from metastatus where healthtime::date = date '2013-04-04'`

Comment: It's possible to create separate indexes on healthtime::time and healthtime::date. I suspect @a_horse_with_no_name is correct in thinking that on-the-fly truncation/rounding is more flexible than the two-column approach.

Comment: Thanks, I went with an index and selecting the date on-the-fly in the end :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not one query, but one transaction... should be fine as well:

My table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE d (t timestamp);
```

Code for changing the table:

```
BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE d ADD COLUMN dat date;
ALTER TABLE d ADD COLUMN tim time;

UPDATE d
SET
    dat = t::date,
    tim = t::time;

ALTER TABLE d DROP COLUMN t;  

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks but for my large database 158.5 million rows this takes forever. Is there any chance I can speed this up? Also is there any difference between t::date and date(t)?

Comment: Well, the better solution would be to use the index, as proposed earlier. Otherwise just wait till it ends :) I think there is no difference between t::date and date(t).

Comment: Thanks, your answer fully answers my question so I marked it as accepted despite the fact on my database it takes too long.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Healthime::date from tbl_yourtable as date
SELECT Healthime::time(0) from tbl_yourtable as time
```

PostgreSQL Version: >= 10

Answer (score 1):

```
select fake_table.healthtime
  , cast(to_char(fake_table.healthtime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date) as "Date"
  , cast(to_char(fake_table.healthtime, 'HH24:MI:SS') as time) as "Time"
from (select current_timestamp as "healthtime") as "fake_table"
```

output:

```
healthtime                  Date        Time
timestamp with time zone    date        time without time zone
==========================  ==========  ======================
2022-04-22 14:20:25.678-04  2022-04-22  14:20:25
```

tested on **PostgreSQL 9.3.25**, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit running on Windows 8.1